# What do I have to add to this iptables setup to allow mysql access through ssh?

Tags: server, ssh, mysql, iptables

I just want to be able to access mysql through ssh, but I don't want to accept everything as well. What's the most secure way to do this if any. Here are my rules:

```
*filter

:INPUT DROP [14:1434]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]

#Input for HTTP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#Output for HTTP
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Input SSH
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9991 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#Output for SSH
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 9991 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#SMTP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to run an SSH tunnel? I guess what you mean is you don't want to open the default MySQL listening port, which is 3306, or perhaps configure MySQL to listen on a different port and open the firewall for that port? If you want to run a tunnel then you need only the SSH port open and nothing more on the server side (that is, for that sort of connection, I don't mean close HTTP ports etc.).

Comment: But when I use Sequel Pro to access my databases, the SSH lets me through, but "MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (4)." "ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 johndoe@192.168.1.87" also doesn't work, but "ssh -p 9991 johndoe@192.168.1.87" does. If I turn off iptables, both work perfectly.

Comment: you normally don't connect to mysql via ssh.  you connect via mysql on port 3306.  as moon.musick mentioned, you could set up an ssh tunnel.  But I think you just want to open port 3306 (copy the lines w 9991 and replace 9991 w 3306) and you'll be happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --sport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

If you use a tunnel and have INPUT and OUTPUT policies set to DROP, allowing `loopback` traffic might be a good idea.

Comment: I added this line to my rules

'code'(-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT and
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --sport 3306 -j ACCEPT)

First with just the input, and then with the output as well. Neither helped. I get the same error. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Also how do I wrap my code in the 'code' tag. I'm sure my current format is very hard to read.

Comment: @Maz if you mean the inline code, just use backticks, like in shell substitution. For block code use 4 space indentation (I guess you figured it out).

Comment: @Maz Just for clarification - I suppose the MySQL server is indeed running on port 3306? `netstat -tlpn` should show it. Also, I suppose the port is listed as open if you run `nmap -p 3306 localhost`?

Comment: It says that the "Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -PN." This firewall also seems to be blocking repositories because I couldn't install nmap without turning the firewall off first. I'm guessing there's a problem with my firewall setup in general?

Comment: @Maz You might try adding `RELATED` state to all those filters containing already `ESTABLISHED`. I generally don't do OUTPUT DROP policy, so I have not much experience about how crippling it is in practice. I don't know Sequel Pro at all, thus I don't know what it uses for connection (does it do its own ssh, or do you tunnel it 'manually' and then connect with the app?), but did you try running the tunnel and then connecting 'manually' with the `mysql` shell client?

Comment: I got it to work!! I was looking through a list of common iptables rules, and found one that that similar to your loopback rule.
    iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
Thank you sir!

Comment: [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/iptables-rules-examples/) <--This is what I used

Comment: @Maz ah indeed, if there's a DROP on OUTPUT, you need to whitelist loopback too, a fool of me not to notice it immediately. I edited my answer, you may accept it or write your own and accept it (it's totally ok in here).

Comment: +1 requires 2 more reputation :(. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Maz I already spent my votes on your question and answer, so I can't help with rep anymore ;)

Comment: I get a `Can't use -i with output' error with this; an update of the answer needed perhaps?